# Simplest way to access Eclipse from java program?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Suppose some java program runs under Eclipse debugger.

Can it access something from Eclipse? For example, current selected node in Project Explorer?

I need to access ANYthing in simplest way. Preferably from single main() class in irrelevant project (project, not related with Eclipse plugins development or something).

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what exactly you're trying to do? Would an Eclipse plugin be what you want? Seems like you want to access Eclipse from the app, instead of the app from Eclipse, and I'm not sure that's a useful thing to do. Also, are you sure there isn't already an Eclipse plugin for what you're trying to do?

Comment: I want to learn and need simplest example for this. I am not familiar with this. If you say that I am obliged to write plugin for this, then I probably believe.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Plug-In and start it with "Launch an Eclipse application" from the Manifest Editor (See the "Testing" section). Within your plug-in you  may add a SelectionListener to the ISelectionService. That should do the trick, I guess.

See: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html